# Is it possible to use a monitor on a script if it fails?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapinghub, spidermon

I use scrapinghub to run my spiders.  I have a FinishReasonMonitor that slacks me if a spider fails.  Is it possible to apply this to a script?  My spiders rarely fail, but my scripts occasionally do.  In scrapinghub it shows script outcomes as failed just as it does spiders if they fail, so I feel like this has to be possible.

Comment: I’m not sure you can reuse a Spidermon monitor without making things messy. Spidermon is very tied to Scrapy. I would just customize the script to send the Slack message.